# Position relative not working with display table-cell for dynamic menu?

Tags: html, css

I've created a horizontal menu composed of links. I need these links to resize in so that it appears directly under the menu.

```
<div id="level2Nav_Menu" class="mega-menu menucol1" style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; display: none; left: 392px; top: 110px; display: none; z-index: 1000;"">
    <div id="overlap" class="overlapmenubg firstlast" style="display: block;position: relative">Advice & Guidance</div>
    <div class="content" style="position: relative";>
        <table cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="">
                        <span>
                            <div class="l2">
                                <a href="">text 1</a>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                        <span>
                           <div class="l2">
                                <a href="">text 1</a>
                            </div>
                        </span>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

*/css styles/*

```
.mega-menu {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #AAAAAA !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: -1px;
    width: 450px;
    z-index: 5999;
}
.menucol1 {
    width: 200px !important;
}
```

Comment: The effect of [`relative` positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position) is undefined on `table-cell` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining position with a location value.  example position: relative; left: 20px

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
position:relative;
```

Now give `left:somepx` or `right:somepx` whatever you want.